# How to put text dynamically into an HTML page

Tags: html

I have a simple text webpage that I intend to upload to ipfs.io Once it's uploaded I won't be able to change the HTML

However I want to be update the text on the page.

How might I go about achieving this? Ideally as simply as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript and fetch api

Comment: anything simpler? I was thinking maybe an RSS feed or similar to display the text?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).